# CSS grid expand/shrink column depending on content whilst keeping other columns the same

Tags: html, css, resize, css-grid, grid-template-columns

I have a grid of elements that I need to resize dynamically. Each column is supposed to fill as much as the page as possible when expanded and the children will fit that size. So I have 5 columns that should have a max width of 20% each. Upon an event happening, the content within any of the 5 columns will shrink to 40px. I would like its grid column to recognise the content has shrunk and for the column to resize to fit its new set width (40px). The other 4 columns should still remain at 20% width. Another event will occur which will remove the 40px width, and allow it to expand to the columns max size of 20% again.

So here is a visual representation of all the columns at 20%:
[image]

And then when the event happens I need whichever column to shrink to fit its content (40px in this scenario), and the for the grid column to shrink with it, whilst keeping the other 4 columns at 20% still.

[image]

I have created a quick demo to play with, but being new to grids, I haven't been able to find the right combination of min, max, minmax, auto-fill, auto-fit, fr!

```js
for (const column of document.querySelectorAll('.main div')) {
  column.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
    column.classList.toggle('shrink');
  });
}
```

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 20%);
}

.main div:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

.main div:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}

.main div:nth-child(3) {
  background: yellow;
}

.main div:nth-child(4) {
  background: green;
}

.main div:nth-child(5) {
  background: purple;
}

.shrink {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your requirement is not logical. You want a "grid" to have a column that shrinks but the rest to retain a 20% width? What is supposed to happen with the remaining space? It's perfectly possible for the *contents* of the grid to shrink though which is what you have already.

Comment: Recall that the columns aren't actual elements... they are merely layout lines to attach elements to.

Comment: I see. I've accomplished it with flexbox, but I was just trying out a different way to see if I could get it to work with grids as well.